# Keyboard input with select case

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I am trying to make a basic calculator and i have my buttons with the number 0-9 and all the mathematic symbols. I would like to link my keyboard (numpad) buttons to them, i did some searching and saw some examples with 'if' statements.
Would it be possible to do this with a select case?
And which Key event is best suited to handle keyboard input? KeyUp, KeyDown or KeyPress?
KeyPress gives me the error that '=' is not a valid operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible with a `Select Case`.
The best key event for this is probably `KeyDown`, so the button will be clicked as soon as the user presses the key. (If you would use `KeyUp`, then it would wait for them to release the key, which might not be what they expect.)
An example of how this might look:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.NumPad1
            Button1.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad2
            Button2.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad3
            Button3.PerformClick()
        'Continue adding other keys here'
    End Select
End Sub
```

You will need to change to names of the buttons to match your code.
You may also need to set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `True` so that the `KeyDown` event gets raised. (You can do this from in the designer)

Comment: could i call the 'Button1_Click' event right away with this or is it better to use the Button1.PerformClick()?

Comment: `PerformClick()` is better!

Comment: You should use `PerformClick()`, because the parameters 'sender' and 'e' for `Button1_Click` are different than for `Form1_KeyDown`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the KeyPreview is set in the properties for the form.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.NumPad0
            btn0.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad1
            btn1.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad2
            btn2.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad3
            btn3.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad4
            btn4.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad5
            btn5.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad6
            btn6.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad7
            btn7.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad8
            btn8.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad9
            btn9.PerformClick()
    End Select
  End Sub
```